# Fibonacci function result confusion

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static long fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
    }
}
```

Let's assume that the user input "java Fibonacci 7", so the result would be like this:

> 1: 1
> 2: 1
> 3: 2
> 4: 3
> 5: 5
> 6: 8
> 7: 13

I seem to be totally confused with how this works, starting with argument 3. When the fib(i) method gets passed 3, shouldn't it return 3 as well since if n = 3 then the sum of fib(n-1) /**n-1 is 2**/ and fib(n-2) /**n-2 is 1**/ is 3. And so on the other numbers forward.

Comment: Ideally the fabonacci starts with 0 1 1 2 3 5... and so on... in plain English next number is the sum of last two inputs

Comment: This seems to be a confusion about the definition of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Each number is the **sum of the two preceding numbers/results** — not *arguments*, *inputs* or *ordinals/indices*. (And `fib(3-1) + fib(3-2)` = `fib(2) + fib(1)` = 1 + 1 = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass 3 to your function it will do the following:

```
fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1) //so we we are into the else statement, because 3 > 1
= fib(2) + 1             //fib(1) = 1 because 1 <= 1 so you return it (if statement)
= (fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1  //2 > 1 => we go to the else statement
= (1 + 0) + 1            //0 <= 1 & 1 <= 1 so we are into the if and return the values 
= 2
```

Comment: I totally forgot that each method call would go through all the statements/expressions within the method itself, but that cleared it up. Anyway, that was one complicated code for me, I wonder how the person came up with that code, or is it a given formula?

Comment: Yes it's the definition of the Fibonacci formula.

Answer (score 15):

**This is a much simpler code to generate Fibonacci sequence like '0 1 1 2 3 ...'.**

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int f = 0;
    int g = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(f + " ");
        f = f + g;
        g = f - g;
    } 

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                           F(n)
                            /    \
                        F(n-1)   F(n-2)
                        /   \     /      \
                    F(n-2) F(n-3) F(n-3)  F(n-4)
                   /    \
                 F(n-3) F(n-4)
```

Notice that many computations are repeated!
Important point to note is this algorithm is exponential because it does not store the result of previous calculated numbers. eg F(n-3) is called 3 times.

For more details refer algorithm by dasgupta chapter 0.2

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int f(int n){
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer c = 4;
    Integer answer = f(c);
    System.out.println("Fibonacci " + c + "'s number is: " + answer);
}
```

Comment: How does this answer a question implied by `confused with how this works`, and which?

Answer (score 2):

My solution using Java 8 Stream:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int n = 7;
        Fibonacci fibonacci = new Fibonacci();
        Stream.generate(fibonacci::next)
                .limit(n)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

public class Fibonacci {
    private long next = 1;
    private long current = 1;
    private int count = 1;

    public FibonacciNumber next() {
        FibonacciNumber fibonacciNumber = new FibonacciNumber(count++, current);
        long previous = current;
        current = next;
        next = current + previous;
        return fibonacciNumber;
    }
}

public class FibonacciNumber {
    private final int count;
    private final long value;

    public FibonacciNumber(int count, long value) {
        this.count = count;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return count + ": " + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the index (n) in the Fibonacci sequence with the actual value at that index. fib(n=3) = fib(n-1=2) + fib(n-2=1) = 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: (I guess it was *argument* - anyway it was not *result*.)

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try this easy code.
It's same like we do in Fibonacci without recursion.

```
public class FinnonnacciDemo2 {

    static int no = 0, n = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This will print series till 8
        fib(0, 1);
    }

    public static void fib(int a, int b) {
        // Terminating condition.
        if (a >= n) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("\t" + no);
            no = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = no;
            fib(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses recursion. It's just a more clever way because doing recursion over the last two Fibonacci numbers saves you A LOT of time for larger indices.

Comment: That global is a bad habit. Why not pass it: `fib(a,b,limit)`

Comment: Yes, we can pass it wit function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Fibonacci numbers are the calculated sum of previous consecutive two numbers. It starts with 0 1 1 2 3 5 8... and so on. So its something like--

```
fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)
       = fib(1) + fib(0) + 1 //fib(1) = 1
       = 1 + 0 + 1 //fib(0) = 0
       = 2
```

***Recursion method is less efficient as it involves function calls which uses stack, also there are chances of stack overflow if function is called frequently for calculating larger Fibonacci numbers.***

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two lines!

Shortest typing to do this (albeit, not the most efficient):

```
    int fib( int x ) {
        return x > 1 ? fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2) : x; }
```

If you want a fast algorithm, give this one a shot:

```
        ///fast version fibbonacci sequence.
        public static float fibonacci(int x){
           float[] sequence = new float[x];
           sequence[0] = 1;
           sequence[1] = 1;
          if (x > 1){
             for (int i = 2; i < x; i++){
               sequence[i] = sequence[i-1] + sequence[i-2];
             }
          }
          for (float z : sequence){
              System.out.print("{ " + z + "}, ");
          }
          return sequence[x-1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci series either starts with zero or with 1, non of which options has the 3 as the third number.

1 1 2 3 5 ...

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...

The usual way is to have the second option but starting at index 0 so that fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = fib(2) = 1, as stated for example here: http://oeis.org/A000045

Answer (score 0):

Is a Recursion method... `fib(3)=fib(3-1)+fib(3-2)=
                           fib(2)+fib(1)=(fib(2-1)+fib(1-1))+fib(1)=
                                          fib(1)+fib(0)+fib(1)=
                                             1  +   0  +  1`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public abstract class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer max = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        BigDecimal[] fibs = { new BigDecimal(0), new BigDecimal(1) };
        BigDecimal current;
        System.out.print("1 ");
        for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
            current = fibs[1].add(fibs[0]);
            System.out.print(current + " ");
            fibs[0] = fibs[1];
            fibs[1] = current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Answer (score 0):

**The method below returns the fibonacci number at index n.**

```
 public static long getFibonacci(int n) {
            List<Long> fibonacciNumbers = new ArrayList();
            long j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
                if (i == 2) {
                    j += (i - 2);
                } else if (i > 2) {
                    j = fibonacciNumbers.get(i - 1) + fibonacciNumbers.get(k - 2);
                } else {
                    j += i;
                }
                fibonacciNumbers.add(j);
                k++;
                System.out.println("Fibonacci Array = " + Arrays.toString(fibonacciNumbers.toArray()));
            }
            return fibonacciNumbers.get(fibonacciNumbers.size() - 1);
        }
```

Comment: What question does this answer, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use  the next formula:

```
private static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What difference do you see compared to `long fib(int)` in the question? What question does this counter-question answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is my dynamic programming implementation using BigInteger.

```
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Topic: Dynamic Programming
 * Algorithm: Fib Algorithm Implementation
 *
 * Author: Chris M. Perez Santiago
 * Date: 4 / 15 / 2018
 **/


  public class Main {
     private static BigInteger[] b = new BigInteger[100000001];
     private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     long n = console.nextLong();
     for(long i=1;i<=n;i++) System.out.println(initFib(i));
  }

  private static BigInteger dpFib(Map<Long , BigInteger> map , long n){
     if(map.containsKey(n)) return map.get(n);

     map.put(n - 1 , dpFib(map , n - 1));
     map.put(n - 2 , dpFib(map , n - 2));
     BigInteger sum = map.get(n - 1).add(map.get(n - 2));
     map.put(n , sum);
     return sum;
  }

  private static BigInteger initFib(long n){
     if(BigInteger.valueOf(n).equals(BigInteger.ONE) || BigInteger.valueOf(n).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
       return BigInteger.ONE;
     Map<Long , BigInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put(1L , BigInteger.ONE);
     map.put(2L , BigInteger.ONE);
     return dpFib(map , n);
  }
}
```

Comment: What question does this answer, and how?

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter a number upto which fibonacci numbers should be displayed");
        int fib = scn.nextInt();
        int a = 0,
        b = 1,
        res = 0;
        System.out.print(a + " " + b + " ");
        while (res <= fib) {
            res = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = res;
            if (res > fib) break;
            System.out.print(res + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer `When the fib(i) method passes 3, shouldn't it return 3 as well since if n = 3 then the sum of fib(n-1) /which is 2/ and fib(n-2) /which 1/ is 3`?

Answer (score 0):

1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13 , 21 , 34 , 55 , 89

```
public void fibonacci(){
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3;
    int count = 10;
    Log.d("DBG",n1 + " , " + n2);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count ; i++) {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        Log.d("DBG",i + "= " + n3+"");
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer `When the fib(i) method passes 3, shouldn't it return 3 as well since if n = 3 then the sum of fib(n-1)…`?

Answer (score 0):

```
package Loops;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FibonacciClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number upto which you want to generate Fibonacci series");
        int x= sc.nextInt();
        int [] testing= new int[x];
        int first_Value=0;
        int second_value=1;
        int third_value=0;
        System.out.println(first_Value);
        for(int i=1;i<testing.length;i++){
            first_Value=second_value;
            second_value=third_value;
            third_value=first_Value+second_value;
            System.out.println(third_value);
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer `When the fib(i) method passes 3, shouldn't it return 3…`?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the code in your question, I recommend you first understand the concept of the [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) sequence, in which each number is the sum of the two preceding ones. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19045249/10819573) has explained nicely how the recursive calls are generating the sequence.

I am writing this answer to show the use of Java-8 Stream API to generate a Fibonacci sequence.

## Java-8 Stream API Solution

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSize = 7;
        Stream.iterate(new int[] { 1, 1 }, arr -> new int[] { arr[1], arr[0] + arr[1] })
                .map(arr -> arr[0])
                .limit(maxSize)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

## Explanation

1. Here, we are limiting the infinite sequential ordered Stream returned by [`Stream#iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) with the help of [`Stream#limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-).
2. We are using `new int[] { 1, 1 }` as a seed where the first and second elements represent the first and second numbers in the Fibonacci sequence. If you want to start the sequence with `0`, you will use `new int[] { 0, 1 }`.
3. Out of the array of the two elements, we are getting the first element by `map`ping the array into its first element and then printing it.
4. The `UnaryOperator` is preparing a new array for the next iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class FibonacciSeries {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int x=0;
int y=1;
Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of series you want?");
//user will enter a number
int z=in.nextInt();
System.out.print(x+" "+y+" ");
while((z-2)>0)
{
int a=x+y;
System.out.print(a+" ");
x=y;
y=a;
z--;
}
}
```

}

Comment: How does this answer a question implied by `confused with how this works`, and which?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using Java8 in much simpler ways as below.

```
Stream.iterate(new int[]{0, 1}, t -> new int[]{t[1], t[0] + t[1]})
            .limit(10)
            .map(t -> t[0])
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: What question does this answer, and how?

Comment: Via this way we can print fibonacci series.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci2 {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int a;
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Number of Fibonacci numbers to print: ");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            sc.close();
        }
        int c=1; /*c current number b last number*/
        int b=0;
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        int bb;
        for (int z = 2; z < a ; z++){
        bb = b; 
        b = c;
        c = bb + b; /*bb last last number*/
        System.out.println(z);

    }
    }
}
```